# Using the KeyDown event correctly

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, textbox

I have the following function:

```
private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
   TextBox TextBox = (TextBox)sender;

   if (TextBox.Text == "Name" ||
       TextBox.Text == "E-mail address" ||
       TextBox.Text == "Confirm e-mail" ||
       TextBox.Text == "Mobile number" ||
       TextBox.Text == "Password")
   {
       TextBox.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);

       TextBox.Text = e.Key.ToString().ToLower();
       TextBox.Select(1, 0);
   }
}
```

My TextBoxes initially have a label set as their .Text property. When the user taps on a TextBox, I wish the cursor to move to the beginning and then when they begin typing the label disappears.

This is working correctly, but the problem is when I tap zero, the TextBox is filled with "D0". It also doesn't handle casing correctly which is why I added the ToLower call. I just want the TextBox to clear itself then display exactly what the user tapped, with the correct case. Other examples of how it's not working correctly is that it'll show "space" if I tap the spacebar.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If I had understood you correctly - 'I just want the TextBox to clear itself then display exactly what the user tapped, with the correct case.' - you do not need to handle `KeyDown` event. Try to use `GotFocus` insted:

```
myTextBox.GotFocus += (s, e) =>
{
    myTextBox.Text = "";
};
```

This simple code above will clear the field, when user starts typing. You don't need to handle `KeyDown` - TextBox is filled automatically when user presses key.

BTW - using TextBox as a name of TextBox is a very bad practice.

**Edit** - after comment

Then maybe this will be sufficient:

```
private bool toClear = false;
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    myTextBox.GotFocus += (s, e) =>
       {
         myTextBox.SelectionStart = 0;
         toClear = true;
       };
    myTextBox.KeyUp+=myTextBox_KeyUp;
}

private void myTextBox_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (toClear)
    {
        myTextBox.Text = myTextBox.Text.Substring(0, 1);
        myTextBox.SelectionStart = 1;
        toClear = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't do this because when the TextBox gets focus I still want to display the label. So the Name textbox will still contain Name until they begin typing, and that's when I need to clear it. Why is it such bad practice? It doesn't confuse me, and it means my variables are still capitalised.

Comment: It is bad practice because you could potentially have a lot of textboxes, which Would confuse you. The somewhat standard practice I use for textboxes is to append 'tb' to the front of whatever the textbox contains. For example, tbName, tbEmail, tbPhone, etc...that way there is no room for confusion, you know what type of control it is, and what general type of data is contained in it.

Comment: @xceed So I've added an edit which should fit your needs. TextBox is a type of a class, and it should be used as it, otherwise you will see that in can produce much mess in your code. Note that a class can have a static method/variable which you will access MyClass.Variable - you don't need an object for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private bool ClearTextBox = false;
    private void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tbSender = (TextBox)sender;

        if (tbSender.Text == "Name" ||
            tbSender.Text == "E-mail address" ||
            tbSender.Text == "Confirm e-mail" ||
            tbSender.Text == "Mobile number" ||
            tbSender.Text == "Password")
        {
            tbSender.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray);

            tbSender.Select(0, 0);
            tbSender.SelectionStart = 0;

            ClearTextBox = true;
        }
        else
        {
            tbSender.Select(tbSender.Text.Length, 0);
        }
    }


    private void TextBox_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tbSender = (TextBox)sender;

        if (ClearTextBox)
        {
            tbSender.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);

            tbSender.Text = tbSender.Text.Substring(0, 1);

            tbSender.SelectionStart = 1;

            ClearTextBox = false;
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your help Romasz and your code example, it's fixed my initial problem so now if I tap space or zero it'll fill the textbox with ' ' or '0', great.

The only problem I have is if I press shift (or return for that matter) to get the uppercase keyboard (if I'm typing in the textbox which has the label 'Name'), it clears the textbox but displays a capital 'N'. I'll keep working on it. Thanks again.

**EDIT**

This seems to have fixed it, added to the KeyUp event.

```
        string KeyString = e.Key.ToString();

        if (KeyString == "Shift" || KeyString == "Enter")
        {
            return;
        }
```

Comment: It will solve the next issue as will prevent TexBox from being cleared (you should also handle other keys). It could be done even easier: `if (e.Key == Key.Shift || e.Key == Key.Enter) return;`. Great that you were able to solve all the problems. When it will be available don't forget to mark answer as a solution, so that it is no longer unresolved.